# How to generate a dynamic table on PDF by iText

Tags: java, itext

I want to create a table programatically as like this PDF [FCController.pdf](http://www.ast-ist.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/FCController.pdf).

As you see columns are Date, Name, Category, Amount. And I want to add a datepicker to change the list.

Can I generate a PDF as I said? Is it possible by Itext?

Comment: When I try to view your sample PDF in Chrome, I only see a page proposing to install Adobe Reader. When I try to view it on Adobe Reader, that software asks me to install Flash Player. After declining I'm shown a black page. Thus... *As you see colums are...* - No, as I see that PDF transports some Flash document which seems to display the main content. If you want to do the same (and so hide the documents you want to create from me), create a flash document.

Comment: No I don`t want exactly the same pdf as the link, I need to generate a dynamic table and control it by search. Do you think is it possible by ıtext?

Comment: PDF by itself is a static format. All the dynamic stuff you see in your sample document is *not* possible in pure PDF, you will need some additional technology, be it XFA, JavaScript, Flash, or whatever technology. You can use iText to embed the script/document/control from that other technology into a PDF but you have to generate that script/document/control providing the dynamic behavior externally.

Comment: If you want to see a pure PDF version of your sample document, click the "Printable version" link in the upper right corner of the dynamic version. The document you are presented then, is how dynamic you are in PDF. (Obviously the layouter could have done a better job by making the date column broader, but that is about it.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to embed a `.swf` file inside a PDF as a RichMedia annotation as explained in chapter 16 of "iText in Action - Second Edition". The book had two examples that showed you how to do this:

- [FestivalCalendar1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=300) resulting in [festival_calendar1.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part4/chapter16/festival_calendar1.pdf)
- [FestivalCalendar2](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=301) resulting in [festival_calendar2.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part4/chapter16/festival_calendar2.pdf)

Although these examples work to some extend, I would urge you not to use this technology. Steve Jobs refused to support Flash on Apple devices and that started the decline of Flash as a technology. Adobe introduced support for Flash as RichMedia in PDF in one of their extensions to ISO-32000-1, but I know from insiders at Adobe that they regretted this. In any case: this functionality is not going to make it into ISO-32000-2 (PDF 2.0), which means that:

1. no other PDF viewers than Adobe Reader will have any interest in supporting this functionality, and
2. Adobe may decide to discontinue support for this functionality.

The example you've shared is nice, and it's not impossible to create such a PDF, but you should reconsider: it's not a future-proof solution.